# ClientError: Multiple different grub/menu.lst files found when try to import ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, aws-cli

Trying to import

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova

to Amazon EC2 with

```
aws ec2 import-image 
    --description "XXX" 
    --disk-containers file://xxxx.json 
    --platform Linux 
    --profile XXX
```

I get StatusMessage: ClientError: Multiple different grub/menu.lst files found.

```
{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Status": "deleted",
            "Description": "XXXX",
            "Platform": "Linux",
            "SnapshotDetails": [
                {
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "images.XXXX",
                        "S3Key": "ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova"
                    },
                    "DiskImageSize": 320673792.0,
                    "Format": "VMDK"
                }
            ],
            "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Multiple different grub/menu.lst files found.",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-XXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to import official Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OVA into AWS EC2?

Comment: Seems that it's an issue with official Ubuntu OVA file. Exporting a runing machine to OVA and import to AWS works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't import officual Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OVA file.

Exporting a runing machine to OVA and import to AWS works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, but I am missing why I can't import it? Thanks in advance.